# Improving the performance of assigning time stamps in an R data frame to predefined intervals

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, lubridate

Suppose you have

- a defined list of named, non-overlapping intervals (e.g. quarters, or software release cycles)
- a large data frame `dfTransactionData` that contains time-stamped transactions (`dfTransactionData$instantId`)

and you want to add a column `intervalId` to the large data frame that assigns each row/transaction to the interval within which it happened.

Below you can see my temporary solution, which *works*, but is slow. I would really appreciate a faster solution to the problem.

```
library("lubridate")
config <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
config$intervals <- list(
  "v4"   = interval(ymd_hms("2001-01-01 00:00:00"),           ymd_hms("2003-06-01 23:09:40.165365+02")),
  "v5"   = interval(ymd_hms("2003-06-01 23:09:40.165366+02"), ymd_hms("2004-02-27 11:48:41.065424+01")),
  "v6"   = interval(ymd_hms("2004-02-27 11:48:41.065425+01"), ymd_hms("2015-06-25 20:36:49.069505+02"))
)

dfTransactionData <- data.frame(instantId = format(seq(from=as.Date('2001-01-01 00:00:00', format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), by='day', length.out=10000 ), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))

TimesplitTransactionData <- function(dfTransactionData) {
  intervals   <- config$intervals
  intervalIds <- names(config$intervals)
  intervalSeq <- seq_along(intervals)
  dfTransactionData$intervalId <- apply(dfTransactionData,1,function(row) {
    for (i in intervalSeq) {
      if (fast_strptime(row["instantId"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") %within% intervals[[i]]) {
        return(intervalIds[i])
      }
    }
    return(NA)
  })
  return(dfTransactionData)
}

TimesplitTransactionData(dfTransactionData)
```

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example?

Comment: Thanks you, I have edited the code in the question; it should be copy/paste-reproducible-able now (provided lubridate is installed). On my system, this already takes a couple of seconds to compute - the real data is much larger.